# Will relabeling a partition destroy data

Tags: partition, parted, xfs, superblock

Is it possible to relabel a partition that was accidentally relabeled with a different file system type? We think we accidentally relabeled sdb1 as XFS when it should have been labeled lvm(8e), after trying to get access to a disk array after an OS rebuild.

Details:
We have a RHEL 5.6 system that had to be rebuilt, and afterwards could not mount an external disk array (sdb). We are fairly certain it had this configuration:

`/dev/sdb1` - LVM partition
`/dev/DBU/lvol0` - xfs logical volume
...
`/dev/DBU/lvol6` - xfs logical volume

Unfortunately though when trying to mount we get:

```
# mount -t xfs /dev/DBU/lvol0 /mnt/t1
mount: /dev/DBU/lvol0: can't read superblock
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes changing partitions format or type will destroy you data
Because before mounting you need format partitions using mkfs command